# Android App Searching Download Folder for specific file

Tags: java, android, download-manager

I am trying to create an app that searches my Download folder for the most current version of a specific file and then returns the path to that file.  I keep getting a `NullPointerException` when I try looking at either the file array or string array with the file names.  The null point comes when I call `downloadList.length;`.  I have also tried `while(download[i] != null) {` but I still get `NullPointerException`.  I am fairly new to app programming and have build a few apps, but none of them access public files. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String dlDir = Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS;
        Log.d("Dir", dlDir);
        File downloadDir = new File(dlDir);
        Log.d("Dir", "Found the Directory");
        String[] downloadList = downloadDir.list();
        // File[] downloadList = downloadDir.listFiles();
        Log.d("Dir", "Created the list");
        int len = downloadList.length;
        while (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            DoStuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you testing on? Its possible that the directory does not exists.  Try checking the return value of `downloadDir.exists()`  to make sure it exists.  You can always create it yourself by calling `downloadDir.mkDir()` if it doesn't exist (granted you have write permissions)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use

```
File downloadDir = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```

directly. It's error. 
Because Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS is the name of the dictionary , not the path.You can use

```
getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```

instead in your activity.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification of the `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS`

Clarification:  I would like to access the downloads folder on my internal storage, not my SD Card.  Does getExternalFilesDir work for the internal storage?

Comment: @AndroidAmature Where is your download dir? You can use   getDir( dirname, Context.MODE_PRIVATE) to get a dir in the internal storage for your app. It's path is /data/data/your package/app_dirname . Is this you want?

Comment: UPDATE: I used `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)` but I forgot the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>` in the Manifest file

Answer (score 0):

Because File.length return to size of file.
Try to this.

```
String[] filelist = downloadDir.list();
filelist.length;
```

or

```
ArrayList<String> fileList = new ArrayList( Arrays.asList( downloadDir.list() ) );
flieList.size();
```

or

```
ArrayList<String> fileList;
Collections.addAll( fileList, downloadDir.list() );
fileList.size();
```

You can help this page. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html

Comment: `listFiles()` actually returns `File[]` you can't store them in ArrayList of String.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I change my answer.